# Method to find sum of a series: $\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \large\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the sum of the series,

$\large\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \large\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}$

and I have no idea even how to start.

The only way I know to find sums is:
1)By geometric series $\large r^n$ where $r < 1$.
2)By partial sums, which I also tried but was unsuccessful, as I was not able to make a formula from the sums.

I can see that the sum is geometric with $\large r=\frac{1}{5}$, but I have no idea how to attain the answer $\large-\frac{1}{6}$
 (which seems to be correct according to WolframAlpha) with the formula $\large S_n=\large\frac {1}{1-r}$.

Comment: 1) works fine here, $r = -\frac{1}{5}$. But the sum is $\frac{5}{6}$. It would be $-\frac{1}{6}$ if the sum started at $n = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I see now that WolframAlpha automatically bounds the series from 1 to infinity, not from 0. Is it much harder to calculate the sum from 1?

Comment: @Akitirija Note that $\frac{(-1)^0}{5^0}=1$. You only need to subtract it to $\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: No, not at all. Method 1: subtract $1$. method 2: multiply with $r$.

Comment: Ah! Very cool! Thank you again, Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to know where does the sum formula comes,

Consider a series with **first term**=$a$ and **common ratio**=$r$
Let,
$S=a+a.r+a.r^2+a.r^3+...+\infty$  $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ **(i)**

Multiplying whole series by $r$ we get,

$r.S=a.r+a.r^2+a.r^3+...+\infty$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ **(ii)**

Subtracting **(ii)** from **(i)**

$(1-r).S=a$ $\;\;\;\;\;$ $\implies$  $S=\large\frac{a}{1-r}$

$\large\Sigma_{n=0}^\infty \large\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}=1-\large\frac{1}{5}+\large\frac{1}{25}+..+upto\space infinite\space terms$
From series $a=1$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$    and $r=-1/5$

$S=\large\frac{1}{1-\large\frac{-1}{5}}$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $\implies$ $S=\large\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: Very cool, thank you, Mann!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric series with $r=-1/5$. The sum is $1/(1-(-1/5))=5/6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{-1}{5}\big)^n$$

So $a=1$ and $r=-1/5$.

Comment: Thank you, dleggas. I see now that WolframAlpha automatically bounds the series from 1 to infinity, not from 0. So the correct answer is 5/6.